# how to install selinux package in a venv, from a self contained python installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

I have built python3.8.12 from source and installed it in /python3 on a machine with no other python anywhere.  there are no "system" packages. (it is rocky8.5 linux)

Now I create and activate a venv from that python:

```
/python3/bin/python -m venv myvenv
source myvenv/bin/activate
```

Now I install packages in this venv from a local repository

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --index-url=file:///python3/pypkgs/simple
```

The repository was built with pip2pi.  this is all being designed for full airgap deployments.

Now I cannot import selinux as it is apparently not aware of the selinux in the venv, and is instead searching the system.

```
(myvenv) [root@node1]# python -c "import selinux"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selinux/__init__.py", line 104, in <module>
    check_system_sitepackages()
  File "/root/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selinux/__init__.py", line 100, in check_system_sitepackages
    raise Exception(
Exception: Failed to detect selinux python bindings at ['/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

I use the selinux package as an example because it is the issue I am currently faced with.  Not sure if this is a wider problem yet.  Haven't tested exhaustively, but have not had issue with any other package.

Comment: it seems like this is the code causing the problem:  https://github.com/pycontribs/selinux/blob/master/selinux/__init__.py

Comment: another interesting note, turns out that there was a system python here after all:

/usr/libexec/platform-python3.6

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess I got it working.  Not sure how horrendous of a fix this is.

First, I installed selinux to the system /python3 (apparently you can't use selinux within a venv - has to be system level?)

And then I hardcoded my /python3/bin/python to this line:  https://github.com/pycontribs/selinux/blob/321d66619ed59bec00a9dc6216ce417d7befec41/selinux/__init__.py#L76